# In Kubernetes, Expose secrets in file as environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

In Kubernetes, how can I expose secrets in a file (in a Kubernetes volume) as environment variables instead?

**Background:**
I followed the [Google Cloud Platform GKE Vault Demo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-vault-demo) and in it, they show how to *"continuously fetching a secret's contents onto a local file location. This allows the application to read secrets from a file inside the pod normally without needing to be modified to interact with Vault directly."*

I would like to know how I can expose these secrets as environment variables (instead of a file) for the other application containers to use.

Comment: How about writing the secrets to file, source it (and run the application) and then delete it?

Comment: You need to run a sidecar like Consul Template to get the secrets into the pod. There's no easy way to share environments across pods, so you'd need to use the file system. Examples: https://github.com/sethvargo/vault-kubernetes-workshop

Comment: is there no way to share secrets as environment variable so that the app container in the same Pod can consume them as environment variable? I had thought reading secrets from environment variables is a better practice than from files

Comment: i found something which reads from Vault and populates Kubernetes Secrets: https://itnext.io/effective-secrets-with-vault-and-kubernetes-9af5f5c04d06

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to inject the secrets from the file into the application container.

First, the secrets file should be in the form `KEY="VALUE"` on each line.
For those using Consul Template to get the secrets from Vault, you can do it as such:

```
- name: CT_LOCAL_CONFIG
      value: |
        vault {
          ssl {
            ca_cert = "/etc/vault/tls/ca.pem"
          }
          retry {
            backoff = "1s"
          }
        }
        template {
          contents = <<EOH
        {{- with secret "secret/myproject/dev/module1/mongo-readonly" }}
        MONGO_READ_HOSTNAME="{{ .Data.hostname }}"
        MONGO_READ_PORT="{{ .Data.port }}"
        MONGO_READ_USERNAME="{{ .Data.username }}"
        MONGO_READ_PASSWORD="{{ .Data.password }}"
        {{- end }}
        {{- with secret "secret/myproject/dev/module2/postgres-readonly" }}
        POSTGRES_READ_HOSTNAME="{{ .Data.hostname }}"
        POSTGRES_READ_PORT="{{ .Data.port }}"
        POSTGRES_READ_USERNAME="{{ .Data.username }}"
        POSTGRES_READ_PASSWORD="{{ .Data.password }}"
        {{- end }}
        EOH
          destination = "/etc/secrets/myproject/config"
        }
```

This will result in a secrets file in the correct `KEY="VALUE"` form.

From the secrets file, which is shared to the app container through `volumeMount`, we can inject the secrets as environment variables like this:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]  # for Python image, /bin/sh doesn't work, /bin/bash has source
args:
  - source /etc/secrets/myproject/config;
    export MONGO_READ_HOSTNAME;
    export MONGO_READ_PORT;
    export MONGO_READ_USERNAME;
    export MONGO_READ_PASSWORD;
    export POSTGRES_READ_HOSTNAME;
    export POSTGRES_READ_PORT;
    export POSTGRES_READ_USERNAME;
    export POSTGRES_READ_PASSWORD;
    python3 my_app.py;
```

In this way, we don't have to modify existing application code which expects secrets from environment variables (used to use Kubernetes Secrets).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @cryanbhu this actually saved me.

It is also possible to export all the variables without having to list them out:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]  # you can also just use sh for other images
args:
  - source /etc/secrets/myproject/config;
    export $(cut -d= -f1 /etc/secrets/myproject/config);
    python3 my_app.py;
```

confirmed that works for me :)